# SD value not showed in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset:

```
structure(list(CAMPAMENTO = c("Futura Esperanza", "Futura Esperanza", 
"Futura Esperanza", "Futura Esperanza", "Futura Esperanza", "Nuevo Amanecer", 
"Nuevo Amanecer", "Nuevo Amanecer", "Nuevo Amanecer", "Nuevo Amanecer", 
"Nuevo Amanecer", "Laderas de Angelmó", "Laderas de Angelmó", 
"Laderas de Angelmó", "Laderas de Angelmó", "Laderas de Angelmó", 
"Laderas de Angelmó", "Laderas de Angelmó", "Pelluhuin 1", 
"Pelluhuin 1", "Pelluhuin 1", "Pelluhuin 1", "Pelluhuin 1", "Pelluhuin 1", 
"Pelluhuin 1", "Pelluhuin 2", "Pelluhuin 2", "Pelluhuin 2", "Pelluhuin 2", 
"Pelluhuin 2", "Mediaguas", "Mediaguas", "Mediaguas", "Mediaguas", 
"Mediaguas", "Mediaguas", "Mediaguas", "Mediaguas", "Mediaguas", 
"Mediaguas"), CEO = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L), ceo = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -40L), .Names = c("CAMPAMENTO", "CEO", "ceo"
))
```

I can calculate the mean and sd of columns CEO and ceo, for example:

```
mean(df$ceo, na.rm = T)
[1] 1
```

And sd,

```
sd(df$ceo, na.rm = T)
[1] 3
```

But when

```
df %>% 
  group_by(CAMPAMENTO) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), 
            "CEO" = mean(CEO), "SD CEO" = sd(CEO),
            "ceo" = mean(ceo), "SD ceo" = sd(ceo))
```

the result is

[image]

But no sd result is show.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably because they are integer values, try converting these cols with `as.double`

Comment: no, `sd`, `mean` and so on try to coherce if possible. Intergers are no problem as they are simply coherced to double.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that calculation within `summarise` is done consecutively. `sd(CEO)` for example is based on the previously build new column `mean(CEO)`, hence the `NA` or more precise `NaN`, since `sd(mean(d$CEO))` is `NA`.

Naming your columns fixes this:

```
## Not working
df %>% 
  group_by(CAMPAMENTO) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), 
            "CEO" = mean(CEO), 
            "SD CEO" = sd(CEO),
            "ceo_mean" = mean(ceo), 
            "SD ceo" = sd(ceo))

## Working
df %>% 
  group_by(CAMPAMENTO) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), 
            "Mean_CEO" = mean(CEO), 
            "SD CEO" = sd(CEO),
            "Mean_ceo" = mean(ceo), 
            "SD ceo" = sd(ceo))
```